# Dynamically pass a url parameter from one page to another when clicking <a href...> with event listener

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

I am trying to send a url parameter (in this instance an ID) to another page when clicking on one of the links. I have experimented with a number of methods and found one that *NEARLY* works, except that when I click a non-link element (such as a form button) it will still append the url.

The event listener is as follows:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var href = e.target.getAttribute("href");
    if(href) {
        location.href = href + "?id="+id_search_input;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The links:

```
    <ul id="nav_ul">
        <li><a href="ask_q.html">Ask Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

What I'm trying to pass to the URL: `?id=0123456789`

I suppose that the event listener needs to be on something other than click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's pure JS. I just added a class on the `<a>` tags but you could just grab the `<ul>` and dig down if you wanted to.

```
var navElms = document.getElementsByClassName('nav'),
i;
for(i = 0; i < navElms.length; i++) {
    navElms[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.getAttribute("href"),
        test = document.getElementById('test');
        test.innerHTML = "<p>" + href + "?id=234234234</p>";

    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/31nbwuxv/

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener onto the uls id, then change the url on click

```
<ul id="nav_ul">
        <li><a href="ask_q.html" >Ask Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="page1.html" >Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html" >Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$('#nav_ul').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    $(this).before($(this).clone());
    $(this).attr('href', old+'?123');
    $(this).remove();
})
```

Try it here: (Updated)
http://jsfiddle.net/04cx09c1/2/

Comment: After two clicks on the same link You got id attribute added twice: `?id=0123456789?id=0123456789` -- it's ok?

Comment: @rims interesting, standby